# react-jazzicon metamask autogenerated image cropped as a square instead of a circle

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, metamask

I am attempting to obtain the autogenerated Metamask account images as a square image in a react app. I am currently using the react-jazzicon library.

```
<Jazzicon diameter={100} seed={jsNumberForAddress(walletID)} />
```

jazzicon image result

[image: 1]

However, it seems that the images are generated as circular images. The Jazzicon component takes in a diameter attribute.

Is there a way to override this or crop it to have it as a square image?

I've also tried simply adding a className and then adding CSS styling. But that does not seem to work. People have suggested this before to override styling of components from imported libraries. However, it seems that it does not have a classname attribute.

```
.className :global(.lib-component-classname){
  // Style here apply to component that's imported from libs
}
```

https://github.com/marcusmolchany/react-jazzicon

Answer (score 0):

There is a lib that solve this problem (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cfx-kit/wallet-avatar)

```
import { generateAvatarURL } from '@cfx-kit/wallet-avatar'

export default function App() {
    // ...
    return <img src={generateAvatarURL(account)} alt='account-avatar' />
}
```